# Biblioteca TensorFlow e XGboost via pip

Tags: python, pip

Como faço para instalar as bibliotecas TensorFlow e o XGboost via pip na versão 3.7.2 do Python? Não estou conseguindo. Pesquisei e as informações que consegui foi que eles só funcionam em versões anteriores do Python, é isso mesmo? Obrigado desde já.

Comment: A última versão do TensorFlow é compatível com Python 3.6.x. https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Answer (score 0):

TF + XGboost via pip **não** funciona com a 3.7.2. Como o Marcelo Uchimura comentou, tem que ser o 3.6.x. E mesmo o 3.6.x é bem chato de instalar, sugiro versões anteriores por enquanto.